# Conditional logic in simple_form not working in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

Trying to include conditional logic within my form.  If the user choose a certain type, then information shows up that is associated with that type.  How can I make this happen within the form?

```
<%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :title %>
        <%= f.input :image %>
        <%= f.input :description %>
        <%= f.input :link %>
        <%= f.collection_select :typeof, Post::TYPEOFS, :to_s, :humanize %>

        <% if @post.typeof.include?('audio') %>
            <p>Audio Selected</p>
            <% else %>
            <p>Something else selected</p>
            <% end %>

        <%= f.input :typeof %>
        <%= f.input :approve %>

        <%= f.button :submit, "Submit", class: "button" %>

    <% end %>
```

Comment: What's the data, and the type of the data, you're comparing? Seems like simple debugging so far.

Comment: @DaveNewton its just a string for varialbe typeof.

Comment: @muistooshort so you saying javascript is the best solution?

Comment: @CCEvans ... Either log the value of `typeof` and see if using `include?` with a string makes sense, or go to the console and get the post and check it manually, etc. If `Post#typeof` is a string, and it includes the exact string "audio", then the if statement will work. If it's not working, then there's missing information.